# Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission' failed when compiling web site on a Network Share or Intranet Project

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, webforms

I have been using Windows 7 for a while but have not had to work with a particular legacy intranet application since my upgrade. Unfortunately, this application is setup as an ASP.NET Website project hosted on an intranet server. When I have the website open in Visual Studio 2008 and try to debug it, I receive the following compiler error:

**Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission' failed**

To resolve this issue on Windows Vista machines, I would change the machine's .NET Security Configuration trust level to full for the local intranet ([fix outlined here](http://dotnetslackers.com/Security/re-50692_System_Web_AspNetHostingPermission_when_Accessing_Network_or_Intranet_Projects_using_Visual_Studio_2005.aspx)). I believe this configuration utility relied upon the mscorcfg.msc which from some cursory research appears to be apart of the .NET 2.0 SDK. I have tried to follow the instructions from this [Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=320268) running the command below to no avail.

```
Drive:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url
"file:////\\computername\sharename\*" FullTrust -exclusive on
```

Presently, I have the following .NET, ASP.NET, and .NET SDK components installed on my machine

- Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2
- Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 3.5
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 1.0
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2008 Tools
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework Tools - enu
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Headers and Libraries
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 SDK Reference Assemblies and IntelliSense
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Tools
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Win32 Tools
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 (6001.18000.367)

Do I need to install the .NET 2.0 SDK? Am I issuing the `caspol` command incorrectly? Is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some additional digging I came across a blog post by Aaron Stebner covering [Details about setup for the .NET Framework 2.0 configuration tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/01/23/516671.aspx). Stebner details how the Configuration Utility was removed from the .NET redistributable and placed only in the SDK. Not a big deal a few years ago but now that the community relies upon newer SDKs and only installs the redistributable / compact versions of the framework we have lost access to the .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration Tool.

The official answer from Microsoft is to [Configure Security Policy Using the Code Access Security Policy Tool (Caspol.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0ke3k86.aspx). Unfortunately, this command line utility did not work for me. I however, do not rule out user error as to why it failed.

Ultimately, Stebner solved my issue because he provides an [installer for the configuration tool](http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog%7C_Tools/configwizard.zip). Which once I had the configuration utility installed allowed me follow the steps outlined in th [DotNetSlackers article System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission when Accessing Network or Intranet Projects using Visual Studio 2005](http://dotnetslackers.com/Security/re-50692_System_Web_AspNetHostingPermission_when_Accessing_Network_or_Intranet_Projects_using_Visual_Studio_2005.aspx) which I have paraphrased into steps below.

To change the local machine's .NET Security Settings goto

Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration

Fully expand *My Computer* and select *Runtime Security Policy*. On the right, choose *Adjust Zone Security*. Leave the default option (Make changes to this computer) and hit next. Choose *Local Intranet* and change the trust level to *Full Trust*. Then choose Next and then Finish. Restart Visual Studio and you should be all set.

Answer (score 8):

Try to change the application pool setting `Load User Profile` to `True`.

In Windows 7 it is set to `False` by default. It seems that in Windows Vista IIS 7 sets this  automatically for you.

Comment: Is this true for something running under Visual Studio's Cassini? I don't have IIS installed locally.

Answer (score -1):

this problem happens to me and the solution was easy, I just add permission fro the application pool user on the physical files, then make IISReset, and it's working now.

Comment: I haven't thought about this problem in almost two years. Could you please provide additional context and some screen shots for your solution? As it stands this answer is a bit vague.