# C# code all of a sudden crashing IE

Tags: c#, asp.net

My C# code, ASP.NET, was working perfectly fine on my computer untill I moved it to another pc through remote desktop control. The exact same code works on my computer but on the other computer shortly after I run the application IE crashes...Visual studio gives the below errors. IE version is the same on both PCs and the errors look something permission related, what do you think?

[image]

Comment: Please can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769040/request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-web-aspnethostingpermission-failed-w to see if your question is a duplicate? If not, what are the differences?

Comment: This user is shifting to a different OS. For me the OS are the same, I am currently waiting for an admin on my side to give me more authority as I think the permission is what is causing the errors. After reading the solution it DOES seem like it was a permission issue, I will post feedback on here once I am given greater authority.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run aspnet_regiis to grant ASP.NET permission to run in IIS? You do that with the following command:

```
aspnet_regiis -ga myaspnetuserid
```

replace myaspnetuserid with the id of the user you are using to host the site.